# Free memory of an object in Java

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I created a class (assuming the Tree). Then I initialize an instance:

```
Tree a = new Tree()
```

Now I want to delete instance a and free memory allocated for it. How I can do?
I hope you help me solve this problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: Assign null to your reference a. Either call gc explicity by calling System.gc() or Runtime.getRuntime().gc(). But you cannot ensure that the gc is called.

Comment: Google Java Garbage Collection

Comment: Or to read the full explanation: Java memory management

Comment: If you need to free up memory for a created object, use C. In Java, memory is released undeterministically.

Comment: @Shriram Please post your comment as a solution so that it can be accepted by the OP to avoid a hung question

Answer (score 0):

You should dereference the object.then automatically during garbage collection memory will be deallocated.
Dereferenceing can be done by
Tree a = null;

Comment: "Dereference" != "Remove a referenece". It actually means "use a reference".

Comment: Then to remove an reference ...what do they say..???

Comment: I don't think there is a special term for it.

Comment: Can u explain dereference in detail

Answer (score 0):

I think that assigning a null value to an instance of a class will empty it, deleting any memory for it.
Previous code:

```
Tree a;
a = new Tree();
```

New code:

```
Tree a;
a = new Tree();
//Empty out Tree 'a'
a = null;
```